# iOS consume WCF Service using HTTPS

Tags: ios, web-services, wcf-security, wcf

I'm developing a iPad application that will consume a WCF Service HTTPS (using soap probably).

I used NSURLConnection on iPad to connect to HTTP web service and worked fine. But the WCF Service will use HTTPS. 
The WCF as some different configuration (eg. security mode: Transport,Message and TransportWithMessageCredential).

Is there any limitation on iPad to consume a WCF service using HTTPS? What is the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NSURLConnection itself. If you want to handle the security credentials while connecting to the server you have to look into the below methods,

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

The below sample project from Apple will help you,

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html